# C++ array class with function operator for assignment

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, operator-overloading

I want to write my own 2d array class. I want the class to be able to assign a value to an element like this.

```
a(0,0) = 1
```

I know this must be possible because I can do it with the matrix classes from [blaze](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and [eigen](https://code.google.com/p/blaze-lib/). My first idea was to overload the function operator `()`, which already works great to access the elements. When I try to assign a value with `a(0,2) = 0;` I get a compiler error.

```
lvalue required as left operand of assingment
```

What operator do I have to overload that the assignment also works?

Comment: You have to return a reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to build a function with this prototype:

`T& operator()(std::size_t, std::size_t);`

Where `T` is your element type. This function needs to return a *reference* to an element in the array. This allows you to modify the value of the element via that reference in the caller.

As well as the above, you ought to provide the function

`const T& operator()(std::size_t, std::size_t) const;`

for read-only element access. I've rather dogmatically insisted on `std::size_t` for your indexing. In reality, you might want a `typedef` of your own to stand in for the index type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide two overloads - one `const` and another one not, returning a reference. For example:

```
template <typename TVal> class val {
  std::map<int, TVal> values;

public:
  // the distinction is between a const version ...
  TVal operator()(int key) const {
    auto found = values.find(key);
    if (found != values.end())
      return found->second;

    return TVal();
  }

  // ... and a non-const, returning a reference
  TVal& operator()(int key) {
   return values[key];
  }
};
```

and then you can use it as follows:

```
val<int> v;
v(1) = 41;
v(1)++;
std::cout << v(1) << std::endl; // -> 42
std::cout << v(2) << std::endl; // -> 0
```

Comment: P.S. my answer is slightly late (see @Bathsheba's one). As for `int` vs `size_t`: one needs to know what is the desired key type - an unsigned range or not

Answer (score 0):

Please post the compile-error, for others to see and precisely answer it.

Having said that, I am pretty sure that it is because you are not returning a reference from your operator.